# How to convert file to base64 format in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, converters

In the flutter web dart:io library is not supporting for conversion. Do we have any other way to convert the File to Base64 format in Flutter Web.

Comment: i am pretty sure you can use [base64](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/base64-constant.html) top level constant

Comment: File type should convert to base 64 in web

Comment: `final bytes = html.File(pickedFile.path.codeUnits, pickedFile.path);
Uint8List b = Uint8List(bytes.toString().length);
img64 = Base64Encoder().convert(b);`